# is frola paste an accurate translation of this pastrie/cake or is it a translator failed attempt to translate a name?

Tags: translation

How is this cake/pastrie called in English? The name it's from spanish. The red paste is membrillo (quince)

[image]

Comment: I would describe this as a fruit pie with a lattice crust. What language is the translation from? frola sounds like a transliteration of farawla (strawberry) from arabic.

Comment: it's from spanish. The red paste is membrillo (quince) . Yes in a general sense it's a fruit pie but with some specific characteristics (such as the particular fruit it's made of and other ingredients)

Comment: Would you add your description to your question please? Those details are not apparent from the picture.

Comment: @ColleenV is it better now? I could paste the list of ingredients

Comment: I think your edit fine. It looked like a strawberry rhubarb pie to me, but maybe that's just because it is one of my favorites ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good name for this would be a quince pie with [lattice crust](http://www.bonappetit.com/recipe/classic-sour-cherry-pie-with-lattice-crust). I have no idea why the translator used the word **frola**: **paste** could be a mis-translation of pastry, which the pie base and lattice are made from.

Comment: Or just [*lattice (fruit) **pie***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bakewell+tart&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV4rCxkafVAhUlDsAKHVADAn4Q_AUICigB&biw=1130&bih=883#tbm=isch&q=lattice+pie), since it's contextually obvious that the "lattice" attribute only applies to the top crust.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Looks like a _tart_ to me. But I'm old fashion, perhaps.

Comment: @P.E.Dant, a **tart** does not have a top crust. http://www.thekitchn.com/pie-vs-tart-whats-the-differen-68710

Comment: @JavaLatte That's what I meant by "old fashion". A pie like this was called a "tart" when I was a lad. We would ask cook for "cherry tart" or "tarte tatin" (apple) and depending upon cook's mood, we would get a tart covered with lattice or unadorned. Either way, it was a "tart" unless it was large enough to serve a dozen people, and then it was a "pie". You'll find this in OED, yclept _"Obs"_. (Good to see you back—your absence was noted!)